# Change :ls to bring up ibuffer in Emacs evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

Out of the box, `:ls` in evil-mode invokes `M-x list-buffers`. What do I need to put into my .emacs to rebind this to run `M-x ibuffer`instead?

Answer (score 1):

Changing this has nothing to do with evil-mode: `(defalias 'list-buffers 'ibuffer)`

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `(defalias 'list-buffers 'ibuffer)` didn't work for me.

In looking at source file 'evil-maps.el' I found another method.

Add to your .emacs file:

```
  ;; bind ':ls' command to 'ibuffer instead of 'list-buffers
    (evil-ex-define-cmd "ls" 'ibuffer)
```

This method should be able to map *any* evil ex command.